# Fast averaging of 3D sub matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, submatrix

Let the size of my matrix `A` is `sx x sy x sz`.  I want to get a matrix `B` (with the same size as `A`) where the element of B at `(x,y,z)` represents the average of the `n x n x n` submatrix extracted from the same position at `A`.

How can I do it?

I know I can do this using `convn` or using 3 `for` loops, but it will be very slow.

The matrix `A` of size `200 x 200 x 150` is in `double` precision on my machine when I use `n = 9` takes around 20 to 30 seconds.

Comment: `convn` is likely the fastest way to do this so if that's too slow for you, then we probably don't have much to suggest.

Comment: Try to exploit GPU if available to you. GPUs excel at doing convolutions.

Comment: Can you provide the specs of your machine?  For me, it takes on average about 1 second... which I consider quite fast for that relatively large amount of data and the kernel you specified.  It may simply be your machine that is limiting performance.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) from the Image Processing Toolbox.  `imfilter` is essentially an optimized convolution and correlation pipeline that takes advantage of the [Intel Integrated Performance Primitives](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp).  Just as a simple test, let's create a random `double` precision 200 x 200 x 150 3D matrix and we want to find the average of 9 x 9 x 9 pixel neighbourhoods as you said:

```
A = rand(200,200,150);
kernel = (1/9^3)*ones(9,9,9);
B = imfilter(A, kernel);
```

This actually runs quite fast on my machine.  My specs are a MacBook Pro with 16GB of RAM running a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 processor.

Just to satisfy curiosity, I used [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) to time how long this operation takes once you allocate the kernel and the matrix:

```
A = rand(200,200,150);
kernel = (1/9^3)*ones(9,9,9);
B = imfilter(A, kernel);
t = timeit(@() imfilter(A, kernel));
```

On average, the above code runs for about 1.1393 seconds:

```
>> t

t =

    1.1393
```

Unless you migrate over to GPUs, this to me is the fastest way you're ever going to get it... especially because you have 150 slices of 200 x 200 2D data you have to process with each point collecting a 9 x 9 x 9 volume of elements.